# Use form_class in base template in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-haystack

I use `django-haystack` and it has a view `SearchView` and a form `SearchForm`. I see this `SearchForm` in my `SearchView` on a page `/search/` and it works like a charm.

But I want the search form in all my pages. So I need to place it in my template `base.html` instead of a page specific template `search.html`.

But the context variable `{{ form }}` is only available in my view `SearchView` and not on all pages.

How can I solve this? I think a context processor or middleware will do it but it seems kind of overkill to do this in a middleware. What is normal practice? I guess many others have stumbled across this problem before me.

Answer (score 1):

The safest solution is to use a custom templatetag - preferably an inclusion tag (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) so you don't override other views's context (since using `'form'` as a context variable is the common practice for views handling a form).

You may still have to roll your own search view (based on the default one) to make the whole thing work as you want...